# Ngninx location returning 404 with

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to understand how nginx works. I managed to use it with a simple sample app, and to make it work for my.domain.com. Now I'd like to do the same for my.domain.com/api, but I keep having 404 error. Here is my code

```
server {
  server_name my.domain.com;

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ec2.tyremotion.fr/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ec2.tyremotion.fr/privkey.pem;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://webdemo:80;
  }
}
```

When I connect with my browser to either my.domain.com or my.domain.com/api I'm greeted with an error 404. When i change `location /api` to `location /` it works when I connect to my.domain.com.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Edit : here is my full nginx config :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is 
ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name my.domain.com;

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://webdemo:80;
  }
}
```

Comment: please show your full nginx config with command `nginx -T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other issues, but this one is probably not what you want :

This config means "when you call to `my.domain.com/api`, use the backend URL `http://webdemo:80`", and that is all :

```
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://webdemo:80;
  }
```

You might want this instead :

```
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://webdemo:80/;
  }
```

Which means : "when you call to `my.domain.com/api/`, use the backend URL `http://webdemo:80/`, when you call to `my.domain.com/api/anything/else`, use the backend URL `http://webdemo:80/anything/else`, etc".

In other words : locations ending with `/` are considered as roots for multiple locations. Other locations are considered as exact locations.